# how to check every dictionary is perfect in list , python

Tags: python, list, dictionary, fill

I have a data set as below

```
tmp_dict = {
'a': ?,
'b': ?,
'c': ?,
}
```

and I have a data is a list of dictionaries like

```
tmp_list = [tmp_dict1, tmp_dict2, tmp_dict3....]
```

and I found some of dictionaries are not perfectly have keys about 'a','b','c'.

How do I check and fill the key is not existing

Comment: What do you mean by perfect? Do you mean all keys should not have None? And what is the question mark represent?

Comment: `if set(tmp_dict) == {'a', 'b', 'c'}:`

Comment: @AhmedSayed I think he means that the dictionary has all 3 required keys.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you want this.

```
tmp_dict = {'a':1, 'b': 2, 'c':3}
default_keys = tmp_dict.keys()
tmp_list = [{'a': 1}, {'b': 2,}, {'c': 3}]

for t in tmp_list:
    current_dict = t.keys()
    if default_keys - current_dict:
        t.update({diff: None for diff in list(default_keys-current_dict)})
print(tmp_list)
```

Output:

```
[{'a': 1, 'c': None, 'b': None}, {'b': 2, 'a': None, 'c': None}, {'c': 3, 'a': None, 'b': None}]
```

Comment: `set(tmp_dict.keys())` and `set(t.keys())` is wasteful - the keysview object is already set-like.

Answer (score 1):

You could try something like this:

```py
# List of keys to look for in each dictionary
dict_keys = ['a','b','c']

# Generate the dictionaries for demonstration purposes only
tmp_dict1 = {'a':[1,2,3], 'b':[4,5,6]}
tmp_dict2 = {'a':[7,8,9], 'b':[10,11,12], 'c':[13,14,15]}
tmp_dict3 = {'a':[16,17,18], 'c':[19,20,21]}

# Add the dictionaries to a list as per OP instructions
tmp_list = [tmp_dict1, tmp_dict2, tmp_dict3]

#--------------------------------------------------------
# Check for missing keys in each dict. 
# Print the dict name and keys missing.
# -------------------------------------------------------
for i, dct in enumerate(tmp_list, start=1):
    for k in dict_keys:
        if dct.get(k) == None:
            print(f"tmp_dict{i} is missing key:", k)
```

**OUTPUT:**

```
tmp_dict1 is missing key: c
tmp_dict3 is missing key: b
```

Comment: You can pass the `start=1` to [enumerate](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#enumerate) so that you don't have to offset it later.

Answer (score 0):

You can compare the keys in the dictionary with a set containing all the expected keys.

```
for d in tmp_list:
    if set(d) != {'a', 'b', 'c'}:
        print(d)
```

Comment: `d.keys()` would be more efficient than `set(d)`